Binding energy in metallic crystals
I have a question regarding metallic bonds.
Let's say that I have an iron crystal (Body-centered cubic bavais lattice), the bonds between iron atoms are (obviously) metallic bonds but i dont know how to calculate the Binding energy.
I read online that it depend on the distance between atoms (which is 2.866 Angstrom for iron) but i didn't found resources to theoretically calculate the Binding energy for metallic lattices.
Can someone explain to me how why metallic bonds seems different from ionic or covalent regarding Binding energy and how to proceed to calculate such energy in the general case.

How do you theoretically calculate the binding energy of any lattice? You place atoms and try to come up with electron wave functions that minimize energy. One would do the same for any real ionic crystal. Heuristic calculations using simplified models won’t do much.
